# Accessing the Windows clipboard

Tags: .net, windows, clipboard

How can you access clipboard content using the .NET framework?

Comment: Your question is not clear. No one can answer such a question as you've asked; they can only speculate.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. Do you want to replicate the value of one textbox in another (and what is the criteria for doing so?), or do you want to monitor the contents of the clipboard buffer for some condition? Please elaborate and try to be more clear.

Comment: simple-, access clipboard content thru MS-DOTNET..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [`Clipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) class and its `SetText` \ `GetText` methods.

See also this tutorial: *[Clipboard Copy and Paste with C#](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial188_Clipboard-Copy-and-Paste-with-Csharp.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Access to the clipboard in .NET is available through the

[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx)

class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Clipboard class. Documentation and demos are in *[Clipboard Class (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx)*.